# Customization grouping do not show up in Import scenario

Tags: acumatica

I have created customization which has 4-5 different tabs and each tab has various groups. Customization is for Stock Item screen (ScreenId - IN202500). I have set all its required properties such as StartColumn=True, StartGroup=True, GroupCaption, etc. However, when I am in Import Scenario (System > Integration > Manage > Import Scenarios) for Stock Items and want to map these new fields, it is NOT showing different groups for all tabs such as

```html
Tab1->Grp1
Tab1->Grp2
Tab2->Grp1, etc.
```

Instead it is showing all fields in single object under Tab1->Grp1->.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. All fields has to be created under FormView tag and then Column and Group. Hence it will display these fields in Import Scenario.